# What is the coefficient of this term in multinomial expansion?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to find the coefficient of the term $(a+d) ^{11} b^4  c^2$ 
in the expansion of $(a - 2b + 3c + d)^{17}$

I understand the multinomial theorem can be used and tried to solve it that way but got confused because of the $(a + d) ^{11}$ within the term. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Tips:
$$(a-2b+3c+d)^{17}=[(a+d)+(-2)b+3c]^{17}$$
Then use multinomial theorem

Answer (score 1):

Write $a-2b+3c+d=a+d-2b+3c$.

Then $(a-2b+3c+d)^{17}=(a+d-2b+3c)^{17}$, and hence the coefficient of $(a+d)^{11}b^4c^2$ is $\frac{17!}{11!4!2!}(-2)^43^2$.

---

Hope this helps.